# Apache Command Line Not Functioning

Tags: apache, module, centos5

Installed Apache Ver 2.2.3 on my vps with Centos 5.6 but when I try the **a2dismod** and **a2enmod** got Command not found error.

What can I do to fix it?

Thank you

- This is my first vps and this is also my first experience with linux and centos.
- The server is running fine just need to disable few modules.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On CentOS there are no **a2enmod** and **a2dismod** commands. To disable unneeded modules in Apache, you need to carry out steps as described at the lower end of – for instance – this post: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-disable-apache-modules-under-linux-unix/

Comment: LOL thank you.. No wonder I searched many pages but none of them is working on centos.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps those commands were not in your path? If the programs are in your current working directory, try ./a2dismod.

To see what path our shell is searching, try echo $PATH.