# How to enable mod_rewrite on Apache 2.4?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, mod-rewrite, centos7

I'm using Wordpress and wanted to enable pretty urls feature, but they don't work, i'm thinking that it's because of mod_rewrite, but i don't know how to enable it on Apache 2.4 under CentOS 7...

I've already try this:

```
grep -i LoadModule /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf | grep rewrite
```

but nothing...
Also would like to know it loading all Apache modules has any bad consequence or is it bad practice?

Comment: there's usually more than just the one monolithic .conf these days. e.g. a lot of distros will put module configs/enablements into per-modules files.

Comment: Hmmm, do you know how centos 7 works now?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I found the way to know if a module is loaded or not, here's to command to list the modules enabled:

```
apachectl -M | sort
```

It will list all enabled modules alphabetically.

Wordpress has an .htaccess but default where it enables `rewrite_module` for its use:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

The only thing that i had to do was add this to the vhost.conf file at `/etc/httpd/conf.d/vhosts.conf`

```
<Directory /var/www/mysite>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    Require all granted
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

That's because I'm handling my hosts in that file. But it could be done at `httpd.conf`, or any other `.conf` file that is Included to the `httpd.conf`

Thanks...

Comment: `AllowOverride All` is important part; and it **must** be inside `<Directory>` block (I've got bitten by putting it in `<Location>` block and it didn't complain, but didn't work either)

Comment: but the dir /etc/httpd does NOT exist on apache 2.4 ! (ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: AllowOverride All has a security risk problem (and performance too). Check https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html.

Comment: I was missing this one so mod_rewrite wasn't working for me. Set AllowOverride to All and it works!

Answer (score 14):

Apache2 ships with executables `a2enmod` and `a2dismod` that will do all the "dirty work" of symlinking conf files.

On Debian based distros, the usual location is `/etc/apache/mods-available/`. Here are the .conf configuration files (when applicable) and a .load file per module with the `LoadModule` Apache2 directive. A module is enabled if there is a symlink to its .load file in the `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/`.

You would, for example, enable the Rewrite module with command

```
$ a2enmod rewrite
```

Comment: Oh, but what's the syntax?, a2enmod mod_rewrite?

Comment: Then you are not running a version of Apache2.4 from an official distribution repository, i.e. installed from other source or compiled manually.

Comment: Noup... that didn't worked for me..., it still says that the command is not found. In centos 7 the location is _/etc/httpd/modules/_

Comment: hmmm, how do i check if i installed it from official repo?, how do i reinstall it from official repo?

Comment: Yep, I wrote in Debian based distros. CentOs is not one.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, i didn't installed it from official repo. How do i fix it?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527652/apache-command-line-not-functioning?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Then this answer is invalid... i specified centos, and that answer says that a2enmod a2dismod doesnt work on centos

Comment: Oh you glorious, beautiful, magnificent creature you! Yes!

Answer (score 10):

```
# nano /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

find

```
follow (AllowOverride none)
```

and change it

```
(AllowOverride All)
```

Comment: AllowOverride All has a security risk problem (and performance too). Check https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html.

Answer (score 4):

In **httpd.conf**, search for **AllowOverride None** and change it to **AllowOverride All**, then restart apache

Answer (score 0):

Yes, changing from "Override None" to "Override All" made it work:

On Debian 10 config file is here:

/etc/apache2/apache2.conf

I don't know the security risks, but it works!

Answer (score 0):

***For CentO 7 Only :***
**a2enmod** is a **Debian/Ubuntu** command. You’ll need to edit the **Apache config** file for a **CentOS** server.

What you’d want to do is edit the **/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf** file and make sure that the **AllowOverride** flag for the  block is changed from **None** to **All**.

Basically it should be something like this:
(Note: there are many comment lines in the default httpd.conf file)

<Directory "/var/www/html">
AllowOverride All
</Directory>

Answer (score -2):

for rewrite module just check this youtube step by step tutorial related to enable rewrite module in wamp apache https://youtu.be/xIspOX9FuVU?t=1m43s 
Wamp server icon -> Apache -> Apache Modules and mark as check the rewrite module option

after that you can able to use url rewriting